# How to changed a part of URL in embeded code from youtube by Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm programming on ASP.NET with C#.
I want to know how to change a part of URL in embed code from youtube by Query String.
for example

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/**5CZobYTEwaY**" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to receive the variable of video by query string and insert instead of **5CZobYTEwaY**.

I will be very thankful if anybody help me.

Answer (score 1):

please replace query string varible "id" with your in below code 
below example work with test.asp?id=5CZobYTEwaY

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%=Request.QueryString["id"]%>' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<asp:Literal` to output a clean string on your page.

Try this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<asp:Literal ID="keyOfVideo" runat="server"></asp:Literal>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

CodeBehind:

```
keyOfVideo.Text = "SomeKey";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add attribute for the iframe while setting it to run at server.

```
example = "5CZobYTEwaY";

ex_iframe.Attributes.Add("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + example);
```